# import large .SQL files with Ruby sequel gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sequel

I am Looking to import(Rather run the schema.sql and seed.sql) in to the SQL server database using sequel gem. Is it possible with the gem? I did some very basic things like creating a database, running few queries etc. But Can not find any example for importing SQL file.

Thanks
j

Comment: Why do you want to import a large SQL with Ruby instead of directly with a database CLI tool? CLI would probably be faster and would need less memory.

Comment: yes, I will do the same. That is a better approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequel doesn't support taking a string/file of multiple SQL statements and running it.  You need to provide each SQL statement as a separate query string.  Some adapters may allow the submission of multiple SQL statements in a single query string, but it is undefined behavior that depends on which driver is being used.